# Who were the 30 Rebel pilots who fought for the Alliance during the Battle of Yavin?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

For years, everywhere (including Canon/legends) it has been said that a total of 30 Rebel ships were deployed in the assault on the Death Star during the battle of Yavin. Most of the sources list the total number, type and squadron color of the ships, but mention a few names, as follows:

8 Y-Wings (Gold Squadron)

- Gold Leader - Jon "Dutch" Vander
- Gold Two - Dex Tiree
- Gold Three - Evaan Verlainer
- Gold Five - Davish Krail

12 X-wings (Red Squadron):

- Red Leader - Garves Dreis
- Red Two - Wedge Antilles
- Red Three - Biggs Darklighter
- Red Four - John D. Branon
- Red Five - Luke Skywalker
- Red Six - Jek Tono Porkins
- Red Ten - Theron Nett
- Red Twelve - Puck Naeco

10 X-wings (Green Squadron)

- ?????

Is there a credible or official source that list the name of the 30 Rebel pilots who fought for the Alliance at the Battle of Yavin?

[image: Still picture from film Star Wars: Episode IV – A New Hope]

Comment: Are you sure there was a green squadron?

Comment: @DavidW - https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Squadron_(Rebel_Alliance)#Battle_of_Yavin

Comment: Is there a canon source for that? It's not in the script.

Comment: @DavidW - The original 1976 novelization of A New Hope, ghostwritten by Alan Dean Foster, mentions Green Squadron.

Comment: If I recall that novelization correctly, Luke was in *Blue* squadron, not Red, and there were *four* squadrons, not three.

Comment: @DavidW - You are right. The movie producers changed the color to avoid bleeding effect with bluescreen. I could delete my mention of the green squad but not sure because it is mentioned in Rogue One.

Comment: I strongly suspect those other names were never chosen, but I think it’s an interesting question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the names listed in the question, the anthology novel *From a Certain Point of View* completes the Red Squadron roster and gives another member of Gold Squadron. Each story in the book is of ambiguous canonicity but it is the only source speaking on the matter, to my knowledge. Additionally, the two stories that provide this information, *Duty Roster* and *Grounded*, lack any strong comedic elements or stylistic choices that would imply non-canonicity.

- [Harb Binli](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Harb_Binli) - Red 7
- [Zal Dinnes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zal_Dinnes) - Red 8
- [Nozzo Naytaan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nozzo_Naytaan) - Red 9
- [Ralo Surrel](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ralo_Surrel) - Red 11
- [Gazdo Woolcob](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gazdo_Woolcob) - Gold 7

We can also make an educated guess by taking the members of the respective squadrons active during the Battle of Scarif (which occurred almost immediately before the Battle of Yavin) who are not known to have died during that event.

- [Torge Gommer](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Torge_Gommer) - Green 2
- [Attico Wred](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Attico_Wred) - Green 4
- [Broan Danurs](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Broan_Danurs) - Green 10
- [Wion Dillems](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wion_Dillems) - Green 12
- [Brace Marko](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Brace_Marko) - Gold 6
- [Datchi Creel](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Datchi_Creel) - Gold 8